# Calculating payout of strategy for two one-armed bandits

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

I am trying to calculate the expected payout of the following strategy:

You have two one-armed bandits: one pays out \$$1$ with probability $0.4$, the other pays out \$$1$ with probability $0.5$, you don't know which is which.

You start with one of the bandits by chance and play this bandit while you're winning. As soon as you lose you switch to the other bandit and again play this bandit while you're winning... and so on for $1,000$ games altogether.

**My question**
How do you calculate the expected payout of the above strategy?

**A thought**
Intuitively this strategy should perform better than a completely random strategy (\$$450$) because you stick longer with the winning bandit.

Comment: The random strategy has an expectation of $\$450,$ not $\$900.$  Intuitively it must be *better* than yours because every time you get a winning signal you abandon the bandit!  You should be switching when you lose, not when you win.  Your strategy has an asymptotic expectation of $\$4/9\approx 0.444$ per game rather than $\$9/20=0.45.$

Comment: @whuber: The last section was obviously not well thought through. I deleted it. Thank you.

Comment: @whuber: ...but I think you misunderstood my question because I switch as soon as I lose.

Comment: You're right--so that means our intuitions agree.  Thus, the asymptotic value of your strategy is $\$5/11 \approx 0.454$ per play.

Comment: @whuber: how do you arrive at that value?

Comment: Let $p=2/5$ and $q=1/2$ be the payout chances and write $f(n,p)(t)$ for the probability generating function of the payout after $n$ plays when starting with the probability-$p$ bandit. These can be encapsulated as a vector $f(n)=(f(n,p),f(n,q))^\prime.$ Your strategy is $$f(n+1)=\pmatrix{tp&1-p\\1-q&tq}f(n)$$ with initial condition $f(0)=(1,1)^\prime.$ The solution obviously is $f(n)=P^nf(0)$ where $P$ is the foregoing transition matrix. As usual, the matrix powers can be found by diagonalizing $P$ and the expectation can be found by evaluating $d/dt(f(n,p)+f(n,q))/2$ at $t=1.$

Comment: @whuber: I tried something along the same lines but you brought me on the right track - Thank you!

Comment: I am struggling to understand why whuber's equation for f(n+1) holds. I understand that pgf of the sum of independent rvs is the product of their pgfs, but I don't see how the f(n+1) equation follows from this. Could someone help me?

Comment: @elexhobby:if you interpret the problem as a markov chain than this is the matrix with the transition probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you construct the matrix with the transition probabilities, then you calculate the long run staying proportions via the normalized eigenvector of the biggest eigenvalue and last you weight this with the probability of payout to arrive at the expectation:

```
(P <- matrix(c(.4, .6, .5, .5), ncol = 2))
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]  0.4  0.5
## [2,]  0.6  0.5
lr <- eigen(P)$vectors[ , 1]
sum(c(.4, .5) * (lr / sum(lr)))
## [1] 0.4545455
```

This strategy is called "stick with the winners" and is especially effective when the differences in probability are big (which can easily be seen in the case of extreme cases). The soccer coach van Gaal is known to use it for penalty kicks.